# What should I call the collection objects passed around between jQuery functions?

Tags: object, collections, terminology, jquery

Is there a commonly accepted name for the objects passed around by jQuery?

jQuery deals mostly in chain-able function calls which accept and return the same type of objects, which are a kind of collection object wrapping arbitrary bits of HTML or DOM nodes which may or may not be connected.

- They are returned by "selectors" `$('#target')`
- they are also created or constructed by various calls like `$('<div>')`

These objects can almost always be a collection, that is somewhat list-like or array-like, even though often some calls appear to deal in single items.

Such objects are not real JavaScript arrays though as revealed by the existence of a `$.makeArray()` function.

The term I most notice is "selectors" or "selections" but it doesn't seem right to use this term for the result of `$('<span>')` as it focuses on just one aspect of these objects, there is a similar problem with the term "wrapper" which I also see used.

The objects are chainable because each and every one of them implements the entire jQuery interface, but I don't recall people calling them 'jQuery objects', it feels wrong.

So there are arguments for not calling them "selections" or "arrays" or "jQuery objects". What about "lists" or "collections"? **When we need to name these objects what do people generally call them?**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Ah yes there is actually a rarely used an wikiless [tag:jquery-object] tag. Why not expand your comment into an actual question?

Comment: My comment was the answer. They're commonly referred to as jQuery objects - that is what a jQuery selector returns.

Comment: Well I can't accept a comment but it's up to you.

Comment: No problem, just added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any jQuery selector will return a jQuery object - that is their common name.

Answer (score 1):

My common use is that I call them what they return and define `$` as prefix in case of JQuery objects. e.g.:

```
<div id="content" />

var $contentDiv = $('#content'); // jquery object which has the div with the id 'content'

var total = 1 + 1; // javascript object
```

My two cents to keep things clear.